# Problem with storing a value in a list c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to c # and I have gaps in programming in it.

I need your help in implementing the program logic.

I am trying to store a value in a list that will be added after the entered command in the console.

The value is added, but when I repeat the command, the new value is not written to the list, it disappears.

```
public interface IDataSource{
    MainRecord Save(MainRecord record);
    MainRecord Get(int id);
    bool Delete(int id);
    List<MainRecord> GetAll();
}
abstract public class MainRecord{
    public int id;
    public  string address;
    public  string activity;
    public  string data_1;
    public  string data_2;
}
public class MemoryDataSource : IDataSource{
    private List<MainRecord> record = new List<MainRecord>();
    public MainRecord Save(MainRecord records){
        records.id = record.Count;
        record.Add(records);
        return records;
    }
    public MainRecord Get(int id){
        return record[id];
        
    }
    public bool Delete(int id){
        if(record[id] != null){
            record.RemoveAt(id);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
    public List<MainRecord> GetAll(){
        return record;
    }
}
public class BusinessLogic {
    private IDataSource dataSource;
    public BusinessLogic(IDataSource source){
        dataSource = source;
    }
    public List<MainRecord> GetList(){
        List<MainRecord> list = dataSource.GetAll();
        return list;
    }
    public List<MainRecord> SaveList(MainRecord record){
        List<MainRecord> list = dataSource.GetAll();
        list.Add(dataSource.Save(record));
        return list;
    }
}
class Program: MainRecord {
    static BusinessLogic logic;
    static void PrintMenu(){
        Console.WriteLine("1 - save, 2 - output by id , 3 - output all List, delete - delete by id , exit - exit programm");
    }
    static void SaveListId(){
        Console.WriteLine("Addres: ");
        string Newaddress = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("List of planned events: ");
        string Newactivity = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Date 1: ");
        string Newdata_1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Date 2: ");
        string Newdata_2 = Console.ReadLine();
        List<MainRecord> list = logic.SaveList(new Program{address = Newaddress, activity = Newactivity, data_1 = Newdata_1, data_2 = Newdata_2});
        Main();
    }
    static void PrintListId(){

        Main();
    }
    static void Delete(){

        Main();
    }
    static void PrintList(){
        List<MainRecord> list = logic.GetList();
        foreach(MainRecord record in list){
            Console.WriteLine(record.id);
        }
        Main();
    }
    static void Main(){
        logic = new BusinessLogic(new MemoryDataSource());
        bool exit = false;

        while(!exit){
            PrintMenu();
            string command = Console.ReadLine();
            switch(command){
                case "1":
                    SaveListId();
                break;
                case "2":
                    PrintListId();
                break;
                case "3":
                    PrintList();
                break;
                case "delete":
                    Delete();
                break;
                case "exit":
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i guess it is because of this line

```
private List<MainRecord> record = new List<MainRecord>();
```

if so, how can the code be implemented to make the recording work correctly?

Comment: In main the first line is _logic = new BussinessLogic(new MemoryDataSource());_ so everytime you call main from your code a new (empty) list is created

Comment: The fix seems simple. Move the _PrintMenu_ outside the loop in main. Then call PrintMenu instead of Main and return to the loop in main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because when you call `SaveListId` it calls back to `Main()` at the end of the method. This in turn creates a new object, `logic = new BusinessLogic(new MemoryDataSource());`. I would start by removing the `Main()` call, since just returning to the caller would be more appropriate, since I assume recursion was not intended.